# cannot access phone directories using adb shell after upgrading to android 11

Tags: adb, shell, android-11

I recently upgraded to android 11. Ever since I did that I cannot adb shell into any of the directories inside the `/mnt` directory:

```
adb shell
taimen:/ $ cd mnt
taimen:/mnt $ ls
androidwritable  appfuse  asec  expand  installer  media_rw  obb  pass_through  product  runtime  sdcard  secure  user  vendor
taimen:/mnt $ cd sdcard
/system/bin/sh: cd: /mnt/sdcard: Permission denied
```

What do I do to regain my access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android 11 sdcard path seem to have changed. The path `/mnt/sdcard` still exists but via adb you don't the permissions to access this path.

But there are alternatives. On the an emulator running Android 11 I can see for example path `/sdcard`. This path however is a soft link to `/storage/self/primary` which again is a soft-link to `/storage/emulated/0`.

Hence you have the following alternatives:

- `/sdcard`
- `/storage/self/primary`
- `/storage/emulated/0`